# SwiftUI. How to notify when the custom binding value changes?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a bit confused. I have some complex functionality. There are several lines with checkboxes. When you tap on the line ViewModel decides which lines to select and which lines to deselect. I created a custom binding for CheckBox, so it should change its state according to changes inside ViewModel. I try to update the binding using `.update()` method. However it does nothing. get of the binding is not called.

Here is my code:

```
let lineIndex = $0 + viewModel.getSectionFirstLineIndex(sectionIndex: sectionIndex)
let line = viewModel.getLine(index: lineIndex)
var checkBoxBinding = Binding<Bool>(
    get: {
        viewModel.isLineSelected(lineIndex: lineIndex)
    }, set: { _ in
        fatalError("Not supported")
    }
)

HStack {
    CheckBox(isSelected: checkBoxBinding)
    Text(line)
}.padding(16).onTapGesture {
    viewModel.didTapOnLine(lineIndex: lineIndex)
    checkBoxBinding.update()
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code about your model and much more code about the View which your HStack belong?

Answer (score 0):

you could listen for changes on hstack with .onChange(viewModel.$isLineSelected) and then in the closure change the value of checkBoxBinding.